# Mustache js takes parent's object scope when none is found in the current one

Tags: javascript, mustache

According to the mustache RFC

> A {{name}} tag in a basic template will try to find the name key in
>   the current context. If there is no name key, nothing will be
>   rendered.

I therefore expected this:

```
var template = '{{#anArray}}{{aString}}{{/anArray}}';

var json = {
    "aString":"ABC",
    "anArray": [1,{"aString":"DEF"}]
 };
```

To give me once rendered:

```
"DEF"
```

However mustache.js looks for values in the parent's scope. Which gives me

```
"ABCDEF"
```

Do the context actually means including all the parents scopes ?

http://jsfiddle.net/ZG4zd/20/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

A bit longer answer. `Context.prototype.lookup` does a while loop, looking up a token in current context and it's parent contexts, while there is a parent context.

Relevant bit of code:

```
Context.prototype.lookup = function (name) {
    var value = this._cache[name];

    if (!value) {
      if (name === ".") {
        value = this.view;
      } else {
        var context = this;

        //Iterate ancestor contexts
        while (context) {
          if (name.indexOf(".") > 0) {
            var names = name.split("."), i = 0;

            value = context.view;

            while (value && i < names.length) {
              value = value[names[i++]];
            }
          } else {
            value = context.view[name];
          }

          if (value != null) {
            break;
          }


          context = context.parent;
        }
      }

      this._cache[name] = value;
    }

    if (typeof value === "function") {
      value = value.call(this.view);
    }

    return value;
  };
```

Comment: Then it must be the same for any Mustache port ? I mean this is not only a feature in Mustache.js ?

Comment: @FlavienVolken I suppose so, it's the same in pystache at least.

Comment: @FlavienVolken ... and ruby

Comment: It's part of the mustache spec, so any spec-compliant mustache implementation does the same context lookup.